# Why i get an error with cygwin?

Tags: compiler-construction, cygwin

```
static jboolean libinit(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint sdk) {
/*
#include <sys/system_properties.h>
   int sdk;
   char c[PROP_VALUE_MAX];
if(__system_property_get("ro.build.version.sdk",c) > 0) sscanf(c,"%d",&sdk);
else sdk = 8;
*/
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"liblossless","libinit: sdk=%d",sdk);
    if(!libhandle) {
        if(sdk < 8) libhandle = dlopen("/data/data/net.avs234/lib/libatrack8.so",     RTLD_NOW);
        else libhandle = dlopen("/data/data/net.avs234/lib/libatrack9.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if(libhandle) {
        libmedia_pause = (typeof(libmedia_pause))     dlsym(libhandle,"libmedia_pause");
    libmedia_resume = (typeof(libmedia_resume)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmedia_resume");
    libmedia_start = (typeof(libmedia_start)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmedia_start");
    libmedia_stop = (typeof(libmedia_stop)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmedia_stop");
    libmedia_write = (typeof(libmedia_write)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmedia_write");
    libmediacb_start = (typeof(libmediacb_start)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmediacb_start");
    libmediacb_stop = (typeof(libmediacb_stop)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmediacb_stop");
        libmediacb_write = (typeof(libmediacb_write)) dlsym(libhandle,"libmediacb_write");
                libmediacb_wait_done = (typeof(libmediacb_wait_done))         dlsym(libhandle,"libmediacb_wait_done");
        }
    }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"liblossless","libinit: handle=%p",libhandle);
    return libhandle != 0;
}

static jboolean libexit(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   int ret = 0;
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"liblossless","libexit");
    if(libhandle) {
        ret = dlclose(libhandle) ? 0 : 1;
        libhandle = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

compile with cygwin give me an error:

```
    /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/bin/ndk/local/armeabi/objs/lossles
```

s/main.o: In function `libexit':
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:247: undefined referenc
e to`dlclose'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/bin/ndk/local/armeabi/objs/lossles
s/main.o: In function `libinit':
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:226: undefined referenc
e to`dlopen'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:228: undefined referenc
e to `dlsym'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:229: undefined referenc
e to`dlsym'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:230: undefined referenc
e to `dlsym'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:231: undefined referenc
e to`dlsym'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:232: undefined referenc
e to `dlsym'
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/bin/ndk/local/armeabi/objs/lossles
s/main.o:/cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:233: more unde
fined references to`dlsym' follow
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/bin/ndk/local/armeabi/objs/lossles
s/main.o: In function `libinit':
        /cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/jni/main.c:225: undefined referenc
e to`dlopen'
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
        make: *** [/cygdrive/C/androidndk4/apps/lossless/project/bin/ndk/local/armeabi/l
iblossless.so] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are mentioning 'undefined references'. This means that the functions you're using (dlopen, dlclose, dlsym, etc) are not defined. Check that you're including the proper header files, and check also that you're correctly linking against the required libraries if those functions come from a shared lib.

Comment: I'm a beginner as dev, How can include in the header files? thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: If someone has an idea...i wait

Comment: The syntax is: #include <Filename.h> So in your case, find which header file those dl* functions are in, and include them.